# Convert SQL query to LINQ or lambda expression in C# and use in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, lambda

I have 3 table 
Tbl_City , Tbl_GroupCities , Tbl_CtrCar .
I want to convert this SQL query to LINQ or lambda expression in C#

```
declare @fk_group uniqueidentifier
SELECT @fk_group= FK_Group 
FROM dbo.Tbl_User
WHERE UserName='meysam'

SELECT dbo.Tbl_City.ID_City, dbo.Tbl_City.Name_City,COUNT( dbo.Tbl_CtrCar.Cur_year)
FROM dbo.Tbl_City 
INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_CtrCar ON dbo.Tbl_City.ID_City = dbo.Tbl_CtrCar.FK_City
WHERE ID_City IN (SELECT FK_City 
                  FROM dbo.Tbl_GroupCities
                  WHERE Active=1 AND ID_Group=@fk_group)
GROUP BY ID_City , Name_City
```

I try it but it's not work

```
 var model = _TblUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "sampleUserName");
    var q = _TblGroupCities.Where(x => x.IdGroup == model.FkGroup && x.Active == true);
    var sample2 =
        (from x in _TblCity
         join a in _TblGroupCities on x.IdCity equals a.FkCity
         where a.Active == true && a.IdGroup == model.FkGroup
         select new
         {
             x.IdCity,
             x.NameCity
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: What have you tried to do? What is the problem?

Comment: i want convert this query to lambda . i'm confused how to convert this , because i have join and group by and nested select

Comment: Have you looked for how to join and group by LINQ?

Comment: yes but i am new in linq . please help me on this.

Comment: I think people would be more helpful if you attempted to find an answer before asking.

Comment: The order of things on StackOverflow is the following : people try to do something, get errors \ problems, then write here about errors/problems  showing what is done and where the error is.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features) the features you have in your query are not yet implemented. GroupBy and i think also subselects will do an

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
```

And in memory it will do the group by or even for each row a new SQL query.

Better to use the RawSql method for this purpose.

But if you realy want to learn LINQ and convert your SQL take a look at [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is done. I found my problem, I don't Understand use two joins and use group by in Linq

I use this linq for the solution and run

```
    var model = _TblUser.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == type.UserName);

        var q = _TblGroupCities.Where(x => x.IdGroup == model.FkGroup && x.Active == true);
        tblCityViewModel = new List<MohasebKhodro.ViewModels.TblCityViewModel>();

        var sample2 =
            (from x in _TblCity
             join a in _TblGroupCities on x.IdCity equals a.FkCity
             where a.Active == true && a.IdGroup == model.FkGroup
             select new
             {
                 x.IdCity,
                 x.NameCity
             }).ToList();


        foreach (var item in sample2)
        {
            var er = _TblCtrCar.Where(x => x.FkCity == item.IdCity).Max(x => x.CurYear);
            tblCityViewModel.Add(new MohasebKhodro.ViewModels.TblCityViewModel
            {
                IdCity = item.IdCity,
                NameCity = item.NameCity,
                MaxCurrentYear = Convert.ToString(er)
            });
        }
```

Comment: How can i this Linq to Lambda Expresion?

Comment: It is choke full of lambda expressions. What more could you ask? If you want to prove to your manager or teacher that you solution uses LINQ then you succeeded.